# How to create a common area between elements in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, svg, d3.js

Who knows how to create a common area between elements in d3.js as pictured?

I know there is a plugin like ***d3-sankey***, but it doesn't really work for me.

Thanks for help!!!

[image]

[image]

Comment: d3.area will serve your purpose. Go to https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/v3.1.0/README.md#area to check out api and try giving values of x and ys based on your squares or rectangles for area generator

Comment: @BKalra I just don't understand how to get the coordinates right. When I specify the coordinates of the corners of one element and the other, something does not make sense

Comment: Would you accept an answer with a convex hull (i.e. `d3.polygonHull`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best solution for my problem it`s ***d3.polygonHull***

Thank you all for your help, especially @Robin Mackenzie

Comment: Yes, this will be the best solution. I did not know about the polygonHull